# How to specify order of Xtext Language generation for the XtextGenerator?

Tags: java, dsl, xtext

We have a project with two Xtext Grammars following the description in this thread: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1079008/

Our Language Generation module has one XtextGenerator block, with two language blocks. One language block refers to the other via the 'referencedResource' property.

It makes sense to put the grammars in one project because they are tightly related, and one grammar depends on the other.

However, when running the Langauge Generation module, the language that is depended on seems to be generated after the depending language, causing a FileNotFoundException for the .genmodel of the language that is depended on.

Why is the language that is depended on generated after the depending langauge? And is it possible to specify the order in which languages are generated?

I've already tried:

- Splitting the GenerateBxLang module into two modules, each generating for one language. However, cleanup is performed before running a module. This causes running the second module to remove results of running the first module.
- Changing the order of the language blocks in the module, but this make no difference.

The Language Generation module code is the following:

```java
module com.a.b.GenerateLang

import org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.*
import org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup
import org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.model.project.*

var rootPath = ".."

Workflow {

    component = XtextGenerator {
        configuration = {
            project = StandardProjectConfig {
                baseName = "com.a.b"
                rootPath = rootPath
                runtimeTest = {
                    enabled = true
                }
                genericIde = {
                    enabled = true
                }
                mavenLayout = true
            }
            code = {
                encoding = "UTF-8"
                lineDelimiter = "\n"
                fileHeader = "/*\n * generated by Xtext \${version}\n */"
            }
        }
        language = StandardLanguage {
            name = "com.a.b.BxLang"
            fileExtensions = "bxlang"
            referencedResource =
            "platform:/resource/com.a.b/model/generated/BxLangSubjectScope.genmodel" 
            serializer = {
                generateStub = false
            }
            validator = {
                generateDeprecationValidation = true
            }
            junitSupport = {
                junitVersion = "5"
            }
        }
        language = StandardLanguage {
            name = "com.a.b.BxLangSubjectScope"
            fileExtensions = "bxscope"
            serializer = {
                generateStub = false
            }
            validator = {
                generateDeprecationValidation = true
            }
            junitSupport = {
                junitVersion = "5"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above Language Generation module results in the following error:

```
359  [main] ERROR mf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher  - Problems running workflow com.a.b.GenerateBxLang: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /model/generated/BxLangSubjectScope.genmodel (No such file or directory)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problems running workflow com.a.b.GenerateBxLang: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /model/generated/BxLangSubjectScope.genmodel (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: did you try to referencedResource the first grammar file instead of the genmodel?

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer Christian! I've updated the referencedResource to the following: "platform:/resource/com.a.b/src/main/java/com/a/b/BxLangSubjectScope.xtext" and now the correct language is generated first. Is there any way I could've found this out myself? I only found configurations referencing the genmodel in the documentation and other examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as Christian Dietrich commented on the original question:

The referencedResource should be the grammar file, not the genmodel. The correct reference looks as follows:

```java
referencedResource =
          "platform:/resource/com.a.b/src/main/java/com/a/b/BxLangSubjectScope.xtext"
```